# Transform dataframe with selected columns to value columns with indicator values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame with 5 columns, each taking values from 1 to N.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : {0 : 1, 1 : 10, 2 : 12},
               "B" : {0 : 7, 1 : 6, 2 : 3},
               "C" : {0 : 11, 1 : 4, 2 : 1},
               "D" : {0 : 6, 1 : 5, 2 : 4},
              })
df
```

I want to turn this dataframe to a dataframe with columns 1 to N where column j is an indicator whether this value is present in the ith row.

I tried something like this

```
(df
 .melt()
 .assign(val=1)
 .pivot_table(values='val', columns='value', fill_value=0)
)
```

but I can't seem to get the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get this ?

```py
>>> pd.get_dummies(df, columns = df.columns)
        A_1     A_10    A_12    B_3     B_6     B_7     C_1     C_4     C_11    D_4     D_5     D_6
0       1       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       1       0       0       1
1       0       1       0       0       1       0       0       1       0       0       1       0
2       0       0       1       1       0       0       1       0       0       1       0       0
```

Or maybe this :

```py
>>> df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.astype(str), prefix='', prefix_sep='')).drop(df.columns, axis=1).groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
    1   10  11  12  3   4   5   6   7
0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0
2   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
(df
   .reset_index()
   .melt(id_vars='index')
   .assign(val=1)
   .pivot_table(values='val', index='index', columns='value', fill_value=0, aggfunc='max')
)
```

**Data Input:**

```
print(df)

    A  B   C  D
0   1  7  11  6
1  10  6   4  5
2  12  3   1  4
```

**Output:**

```
value   1   3   4   5   6   7  10  11  12
index                                    
0       1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0
1       0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0
2       1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1
```